# Ubuntu 18.04 - Sendmail no longer works since Gmail discontinued support for less secure apps

Tags: server, sendmail

Since Gmail discontinued support for "less secure apps," Sendmail stopped working because I had configured it to interface with my Gmail account.
I tried enabling "App Password" in Gmail, either by choosing "Mail" as the app or by choosing "Other" and following these instructions:

```
cd /etc/mail/authinfo/
vi gmail-auth
AuthInfo: "U:root" "I:YOUR GMAIL EMAIL ADDRESS" "P:YOUR PASSWORD"
makemap hash gmail-auth < gmail-auth
```

In /etc/mail/sendmail.mc i added

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp.gmail.com]')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth.db')dnl
```

and i rebuilt

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

but it doesn't work.

To send emails from my web applications I use PHPMailer.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I still use Sendmail with Gmail credentials or should I use another method?

[EDIT]

I think I have solved the problem. After many attempts I changed the destination e-mail address in PHPMailer and attempted a send from my form in PHP. The e-mail was delivered correctly. I restored the old destination e-mail address and the e-mail was finally delivered.

It was enough to create an app password in Gmail, choosing "Mail" as the app and "Other" as the device. I updated the password in my `/etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth` file, ran the commands

```
makemap hash gmail-auth < gmail-auth
make -C /etc/mail
```

and the system restarted.

Comment: No, I don't need to use a mail client to receive and send mail on Ubuntu but of the Sendmail component of Ubuntu Server to be used for sending e-mail from PHP applications via PHPMailer.